# Optimization t-sql query

Tags: t-sql, optimization

I'm newbie in t-sql, and I wonder why this query executes so long ? Is there any way to optimize this ??

```
update aggregateflags set value=@value where objecttype=@objecttype and objectcode=@objectcode and storagetype=@storagetype and value != 2 and type=@type 
IF @@ROWCOUNT=0 
Select * from aggregateflags where objecttype=@objecttype and objectcode=@objectcode and storagetype=@storagetype and value = 2 and type=@type  
IF @@ROWCOUNT=0  
insert into aggregateflags (objectcode,objecttype,value,type,storagetype) 
select @objectcode,@objecttype,@value,@type,@storagetype

@value int
@storagetype int
@type int
@objectcode nvarchar(100)
@objecttype int
```

There is not foreign key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would be easier to know the structure of `aggregateflags` table -- column types and **indexes**.

I would try:

1. **Check** if there is **matching index** on table `aggregateflags`. If not find other matching or create one -- matching index for query is the most important thing (checking **[executing plan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071.aspx)** can help you).
2. Add **[hints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx)** (if you can) `WITH (ROWLOCK)` for `UPDATE` and `WITH (NOLOCK)` for `SELECT` statement -- this help to avoid locking editing or reading data.
3. Change `SELECT * FROM aggregateflags...` to `SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM aggregateflags WITH (NOLOCK)...` -- you don't need data -- you just need to **check if row exists**.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have indexes defined on your columns. If this will not help, use "display execution plan" button in SQL studio and check what's wrong.